# PdfMake | Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './build/vfs_fonts.js'

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, pdfmake, virtual-file

I'm using the PDFMake library and trying to use a custom font in its output.
This font is made for the Persian language.
I followed the steps described on the web page below
[custom-fonts-client-side/vfs](https://pdfmake.github.io/docs/0.1/fonts/custom-fonts-client-side/vfs/)

I encountered the following error when executing the `node build-vfs.js "./examples/fonts"` command:

```
Internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:888
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'D:\ProgrammingWorld\Github_Library\Cyeng\NewProject\onGit\NewProject\build-vfs.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:885:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:730:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

So I decided to change the command and write it as follows:

```
node node_modules/pdfmake/build-vfs.js "node_modules\pdfmake\examples\fonts"
```

But unfortunately, I got a new error:

```
Source path: node_modules\pdfmake\examples\fonts

FILE: Shabnam-Bold.ttf
FILE: Shabnam-Light.ttf
FILE: Shabnam-Medium.ttf
FILE: Shabnam-Thin.ttf
FILE: Shabnam.ttf
internal/fs/utils.js:312
    throw err;
    ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './build/vfs_fonts.js'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:498:3)
    at Object.writeFileSync (fs.js:1524:35)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\ProgrammingWorld\Github_Library\Cyeng\NewProject\onGit\NewProject\node_modules\pdfmake\build-vfs.js:41:4)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1068:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:933:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  errno: -4058,
  syscall: 'open',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: './build/vfs_fonts.js'
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `node_modules/pdfmake/` directory and run `node build-vfs.js "./examples/fonts"`

Comment: Thank you, You saved me.